# How to create multiple Nodejs socket io server-client?

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, chat, node-redis

I am new to Nodejs and Socket.io, and this is first time when I am creating any chat application, so pardon me if I am asking some silly question.

In my web I have to kind of chat services, one is Live debate which is kind of chat room, and another one is private messaging like Facebook Messenger.

I have created both, in private messenger before showing the message I am checking the conversation Id, it's working quite appropriately. Live debate is also working appropriately.

But there is a issue, any message sent in private messenger displays in live debate window also. So I change the Server.js file for messenger and also changed the listening port, now the listening port for live debate is 3000 and for messenger is 8050, but still Live debate receiving the messenger messages.

Am I doing this in wrong way? Is there any other way to run two chat applications ?

I am using this server code

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('redis');

server.listen(3000);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  console.log("client connected");
  var redisClient = redis.createClient();
  redisClient.subscribe('message');

  redisClient.on("message", function(channel, data) {
    console.log("mew message add in queue "+ data+ " channel");
    socket.emit(channel, data);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    redisClient.quit();
  });

});
```

With using Namespace
server.js

```
var nsp = io.of('/debate')
nsp.on('connection', function (socket) {

  console.log("client connected"+socket.id);
  var redisClient = redis.createClient();
  redisClient.subscribe('message');
  var redisClient1 = redis.createClient();
  redisClient1.subscribe('debate');

  redisClient.on("message", function(channel, data) {
    console.log("mew message add in queue "+ data+ " channel");
    nsp.emit(channel, data);

  });   

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    redisClient.quit();
  });

});
```

client code

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/debate');
socket.on('message', function (data) {
    data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(data.user);
    $( "#messages" ).append( "<strong>"+data.user+":</strong><p>"+data.message+"</p>" );
    $('#messages').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#messages').get(0).scrollHeight}, 200);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

socket.io supports the use of different namespaces. You should use that feature instead of creating two individual servers. After that you can use socket.emit to that specific namespace. For more information see the documentation: https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Comment: This is what I want, but with using namesapce, my client is not connecting. I also used 
socket.to(socket.id).emit(channel, data);
This one connecting to the client but not emitting the data.
I edited the question with name space code. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

It's not too difficult, I wrote a chat app, as I think everyone does when they start nodejs, but nodeJS has rooms which are quite easy to use.

```
io.on('connection', function(client){

    client.on('room_connection', function(id){
        client.join(id); // User joins room.
    })

   client.on('message', function(data){
       io.to(data.room).emit('message', {message:data.message, client:client.conn.id});
   });
})
```

This is pretty much all you need. This works for PM's since u simply won't allow multiple users to join this chatroom, and normal chatrooms which multiple users can join.